# How to link angular 2 in node js?

Tags: node.js, angular

Newbie question that is driving me crazy. I am trying to build the ToDo app with the MEAN stack and I can't get the Express server to connect to Angular 2. I believe it has something to do with where I have my `index.html` view relative to the Angular installation, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your project folder struction should like below

**project/server [Node]**

**project/server.js** is your express server

```
// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

**project/src/index.html [angular code]**

You can build angular code into dist using

```
ng build
```

This creates the dist folder with the angular 2 app built files. Now we can serve the app with express.

For run server use

```
node server.js
```

which create server

Go through https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli for more information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you so muck Brijal Savaliya

Comment: Please feel free to up vote and check anwser as right if you think so..